# How to draw smooth quad mesh with Processing?

Tags: graphics, processing, spline

I am trying to draw a mesh composed of several squares using splines in Processing, so far I have tried it

```py
mesh = (
    [100, 100],[150, 100],[200, 100],[250, 100],[300, 100],[350, 100],[400, 100],[450, 100],[500, 100],
    [100, 150],[150, 150],[200, 150],[250, 150],[300, 150],[350, 150],[400, 150],[450, 150],[500, 150],
    [100, 200],[150, 200],[200, 200],[250, 200],[300, 200],[350, 200],[400, 200],[450, 200],[500, 200],
    [100, 250],[150, 250],[200, 250],[250, 250],[300, 250],[350, 250],[400, 250],[450, 250],[500, 250],
    [100, 300],[150, 300],[200, 300],[250, 300],[300, 300],[350, 300],[400, 300],[450, 300],[500, 300],
    [100, 350],[150, 350],[200, 350],[250, 350],[300, 350],[350, 350],[400, 350],[450, 350],[500, 350],
)

def draw():
    clear()
    background(255)
    stroke(0)
    strokeWeight(1.2)
    beginShape()
    for p in mesh:
        curveVertex(*p)
    endShape()
    stroke(*POINT_COLOR)
    strokeWeight(POINT_RADIUS)
    for p in mesh:
        point(*p)
```

where `mesh` is the matrix of all vertices. I want to draw all 4 edges of all squares, how can I do it using splines? Later I will allow users to drag vertices to change mesh shape and I want that shape to be smooth. The final result would be something like below but on 2D plane:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you define `surface`? Right now I'm thinking about using `curveVertex` along each row and then along each column of a 2D list. That's pretty vague, but if you edit your question to include the definition of `surface`, I'll give a full answer.

Comment: @jstl Thanks, I really want to draw a smooth mesh/polygon, I edited it.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but you still didn't show how you initialized `surface` (or I suppose it's `mesh` now)

Comment: I added mesh matrix, just a matrix of 2D points @jstl

Comment: @jstl I readed Processing's reference and did not see anything about creating shapes with splines, I think I need to draw several splines as lines and rows but thy must share vertices, I don't know how to share vertices between calls to `curveVertex()`. All that red points should be shared between splines crossing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation (disclaimer: I don't use processing in python, so I couldn't test run this code and there may be errors):

```
mesh = (
    [[100, 100],[150, 100],[200, 100],[250, 100],[300, 100],[350, 100],[400, 100],[450, 100],[500, 100]],
    [[100, 150],[150, 150],[200, 150],[250, 150],[300, 150],[350, 150],[400, 150],[450, 150],[500, 150]],
    [[100, 200],[150, 200],[200, 200],[250, 200],[300, 200],[350, 200],[400, 200],[450, 200],[500, 200]],
    [[100, 250],[150, 250],[200, 250],[250, 250],[300, 250],[350, 250],[400, 250],[450, 250],[500, 250]],
    [[100, 300],[150, 300],[200, 300],[250, 300],[300, 300],[350, 300],[400, 300],[450, 300],[500, 300]],
    [[100, 350],[150, 350],[200, 350],[250, 350],[300, 350],[350, 350],[400, 350],[450, 350],[500, 350]]
)

def draw():
    background(255)
    stroke(0)
    for i in range(len(mesh)):
        beginShape()
        curveVertex(mesh[i][0][0], mesh[i][0][0])
        for j in range(len(mesh[i])):
            curveVertex(mesh[i][j][0], mesh[i][j][0])
        curveVertex(mesh[i][len(mesh[i]) - 1][0], mesh[i][len(mesh[i]) - 1][0])
        endShape()
    for i in range(len(mesh[0])):
        beginShape()
        curveVertex(mesh[0][i][0], mesh[0][i][1])
        for j in range(len(mesh)):
            curveVertex(mesh[j][i][0], mesh[j][i][0])
        curveVertex(mesh[len(mesh) - 1][i][0], mesh[len(mesh) - 1][i][1])
        endShape()
```

This draws a line across each row, then a line down each column (at least, that was my intent). Note that I made each row its own list, as opposed to having all the coordinate pairs in a single tuple. This allowed me to iterate through the points in a much more organized manner.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I really just needed to draw _new_ splines for each row and column using same points, the correct code is a little different but logic is the same. My mistake was trying to draw a _single_ spline that gone throught all vertices.